# Handle unpaid order

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

Hi,

For my e-commerce application I always use PayPal and an `ipn.php` file for handling the paid transaction with custom variable as `orderid`.

Because the PayPal system can't handle billing and shipping of the site forms, I pre-insert the order in the database and UPDATE the status when IPN gets the transaction Paid.

Sometimes users click on the PayPal option but can close the browser: voluntarily, accidentally, blackout, etc. The result is an unpaid order memorized forever in the database.

Is there a method to avoid this?

P.S. Sorry for my bad English; I hope all is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I set a flag in the database on each order.

So when you save it to your database, the order paid variable is set to false. Then inside your callback URL you set the order paid field to true.

You can then either keep these in the database if you want to use them for anything, or write a script to remove them from the database and run it on a cron job.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But my web hosting dont support cron job.

Comment: Well, you can't run the cleanup script periodically then, just filter those results out in your query.